# Rails 500 Error Log: autoupdate.php and phpMyAdmin doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, passenger

I'm getting an Rails 500 Error. Checking the Error Logs it says:

autoupdate.php does not exist...
phpmyadmin does not exist...

Server-Setup:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Apache
- PhusionPassenger
- Mysql (but I don't use a DB in this app)

The app is running under production.
Does somebody knows the problem?